# Embedding MP4 video with the windows media player plugin

Tags: video, embed

I would like to embed an MP4 video into a webpage of mine. 
At first I was setting the plugin to Quicktime player, but the movie wasn't playing smoothly so I decided to use the Windows Media Player plugin. All of this works, except for users with WinXP. Is there a trick to make it work on WinXP too? This is the HTML I have used:

```
<object classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" width="300" height="150" data="test.mp4" url="test.mp4" type="video/x-ms-asf">
<param name="url" value="test.mp4">
<param name="filename" value="test.mp4">
<param name="autostart" value="1">
<param name="autosize" value="1">
<embed src="test.mp4" type="application/x-mplayer2" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" width="300" height="150" autostart="true" scale="tofit"></embed>
</object>
```

Comment: This is bad idea if you want it to be compatible for lot of browsers. You should consider using HTML5 to embed the videos or use Youtube/Vimeo for max compatiblity or another JS method.

Comment: See my comment on Jorges reply below..

Answer (score 1):

jwplayer is probably the best IMHO HTML5 video player

http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/

And rather than only specifying a single video format you would use along with mp4, ogg, webm etc so that your video would load in most browsers, and mobile devices.

This is example code with flash fallback

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>

<video height="270" width="480" id="myVideo">
  <source src="/static/bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="/static/bunny.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jwplayer("myVideo").setup({
    modes: [
        { type: 'html5' },
        { type: 'flash', src: '/jwplayer/player.swf' }
    ]
  });
</script>
```

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/22644/using-the-html5-video-tag/

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML5:

```
<video width="300" height="150" controls>
<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

[Example with events](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_js_prop)

Comment: Thx for the reply, but the video tag isn't supported in IE8?

Comment: Use [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) it's easy and the HTML5 tags are supported even in IE6

Comment: A note about HTML5 to anyone new to it. HTML5 isn't as simple as just making your video play in a HTML video tag. HTML5 itself forces its own set of rules and isn't cross browser in it's ability. Some browser will play a video with it, others won't. You can't just get it to play any old video file. The video file has to be in a certain format with certain codecs. If you want it cross-browser you need it in mulitple formats as a backup. 

Granted, it's trying to enforce some kind of consistency but be aware that it still wont just play any old mp4 file. You need fallbacks still.